# Auto accept files in Skype

Tags: c#, skype, skype4com

I wonder if is it possible to do autoaccept for incoming files in skype with C#/.NET.

I'm using SKYPE4COMLib, but I can't find a way for this feature.
It has `FileTransferStatusChanged` event, but it fires when file is accepted.

I know that it would be security concerns for making this option impossible to implement, but maybe somebody know how to implement it with `SKYPE4COMLib` or any other library?